# Faster way to loop in python for updating value from a array in python

Tags: python, for-loop, list-comprehension

I have a dataframe **test** which is as below

```
 Student_Id  Math  Physical  Arts Class Sub_Class
0        id_1     6         7     9     A         x
1        id_2     9         7     1     A         y
2        id_3     3         5     5     C         x
3        id_4     6         8     9     A         x
4        id_5     6         7    10     B         z
5        id_6     9         5    10     B         z
6        id_7     3         5     6     C         x
7        id_8     3         4     6     C         x
8        id_9     6         8     9     A         x
9       id_10     6         7    10     B         z
10      id_11     9         5    10     B         z
11      id_12     3         5     6     C         x
```

There are two arrays as listed in the **My Code** section: arr_list and array_top.

I want to **create a new column** such that it loops through each row of the dataframe and then update the value from the arrays as below:

```
for index, row in test.iterrows():
      test.loc[index,'Highest_Score'] = arr_list [index][array_top [index]]
```

This looping takes too much of time for a bigger set. **Is there a faster way to do this**?

**My Code**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

#Ceate dataframe
data = [
    ["id_1",6,7,9, "A", "x"],
    ["id_2",9,7,1, "A","y" ],
    ["id_3",3,5,5, "C", "x"],
    ["id_4",6,8,9, "A","x" ],
    ["id_5",6,7,10, "B", "z"],
    ["id_6",9,5,10,"B", "z"],
    ["id_7",3,5,6, "C", "x"],
    ["id_8",3,4,6, "C", "x"],
    ["id_9",6,8,9, "A","x" ],
    ["id_10",6,7,10, "B", "z"],
    ["id_11",9,5,10,"B", "z"],
    ["id_12",3,5,6, "C", "x"]
    
]

test = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Student_Id', 'Math', 'Physical','Arts', 'Class', 'Sub_Class'])


#Create two arrays which are of same length as the test data
arr_list = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [4, 5, 6], [4, 5, 6], [4, 5, 6], [4, 5, 6], [1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [4, 5, 6], [4, 5, 6], [4, 5, 6], [4, 5, 6]])

array_top = np.array([[0],[1],[1],[2],[1], [0], [0],[1],[1],[2],[1], [0]])

#Create the column Highest_Scoe
for index, row in test.iterrows():
      test.loc[index,'Highest_Score'] = arr_list [index][array_top [index]]
```

Comment: What is the source of the data for arr_list and array_top?

Comment: I think you should be able to do this by converting `arr_list` and `array_top` to dataframes, then join them with `test`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looping through the arrays first to create your new column, then just assigning it to the dataframe will be much faster than looping through each row of the dataframe

71.7 µs vs 2.77 ms (a.k.a. 39 times faster) by my time trial

```
In [95]: %%timeit
    ...: new_test['Highest_Score'] = [arr_list[r][c][0] for r,c in enumerate(array_top)]
    ...:
    ...:
71.7 µs ± 1.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

In [96]: %%timeit
    ...: for index, row in test.iterrows():
    ...:       test.loc[index,'Highest_Score'] = arr_list [index][array_top [index]]
    ...:
2.77 ms ± 49.6 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

As a general rule with adding new data to a pandas DataFrame, you want to do all of the looping and compiling outside of pandas, and then assign all of the data all at once

Comment: Thanks @Jim ! This is pretty fast. Can you please explain a bit on how [r][c] gets updated by enumerate?

Comment: Yeah, enumerate() will iterate over whatever is passed to it, and return a tuple of the index and the value of the iterable. I chose r and c as variable names to represent rows and columns that will be selected from arr_list. Looking at your original loop, the Highest Score you want is just in order going down and the column is determined by the value in array_top